# Academic affiliation when changing universities

Tags: publications, affiliation

I am an incoming student at University A. Currently, I work as a research assistant at University B, but will be leaving this position within the month. Likewise, my affiliation with University B (including email and other means of contacting me through University B) will disappear within the month.

My group at University B is currently preparing to submit a paper on which I am a lead author. Since it will soon no longer be possible to contact me via University B, it would seem to me that listing both my A and B contact information would make the most sense. This way, should anyone wish to reach me, they would be able to do so.

However, all of this raises a question: if I will soon be leaving University B, should I list both A and B as my academic affiliation, especially considering that I will likely have to provide contact information for both affiliations? How should I proceed?

Comment: Look at various papers in your field. Quite often there is a standard (for a given journal) way to indicate your affiliation with B (properly since you did the work there) and you Current address at A.

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/171418/etiquette-for-institutional-affiliation-if-you-changed-institutions-during-the-r/171446#171446

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon the specific journal, you have 4 options:

1. List only University A
2. List only University B
3. List both Universities A and B.
4. List only University B with a current address or affiliation of University A.

I suggest options 3 or 4 depending upon the journal's styling format.
Option 4 probably makes the most sense, but some journals have quirks about author affiliations.